# Fiber product of spaces and cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, chain-complexes

Let $Y \to X \leftarrow Z$ be a cospan of topological spaces and let $W = Y \times_X^h Z$ be their homotopy fiber product. I am interested in sufficient conditions on the map $Y \to X$ that ensure that the cohomology of $W$ is the tensor product of the cohomologies of $Y$ and $Z$,
$$H^*(W, R)  = H^*(Y, R) \otimes_{H^*(X, R)} H^*(Z, R),$$
for any ring $R$ (feel free to add conditions on $R$ here, too).

Is this true, for example, when $H^*(Y, R)$ is free of finite rank over $H^*(X, R)$?

Comment: You might want to assume that the spaces are simply connected. If $X$ is acyclic (same homology as a point) but not contractible, and if $Y$ and $Z$ are contractible, then $W$ will not be connected.

Comment: Feel free to make assumptions on the spaces.

Comment: Singular cohomology?

Comment: Say, yes! Although I am happy to restrict to a class of spaces where this does not matter.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence? I think something like this appears in the set up, for instance in McCleary's book.

Comment: Does that exist if $R$ is not a field?

Comment: Yes, it surely exists but it is the identification of the initial and final pages which might be easier with field coefficients.

Comment: So the idea is that if $H^*(Z, R)$ is free over $H^*(X, R)$, then all $Tor^i$ groups are zero for $i\geq 1$, so the spectral sequence stabilizes on the $E_2$ page. But I don't know about these graded Tor groups to be sure whether this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R$ can be arbitrary. Assume that $H^\ast(Y)$, as a module for $H^\ast(X)$, is free with a finite basis (or even just a basis whose degrees tend to infinity). Suppose also that $X$ is simply connected. I believe that then the answer is "yes".

We may as well assume that $Y\to X$ is a fibration, so that $W$ can be taken to be the strict fiber product $Y\times_X Z$.

The desired statement is that the canonical map
$$
H^\ast(Y)\otimes_{H^\ast(X)} H^\ast(Z)\to H^\ast(Y\times_X Z)
$$
is an isomorphism, for every $Z$ and every map $Z\to X$. I will consider the more general statement that the canonical map
$$
H^\ast(Y)\otimes_{H^\ast(X)} H^\ast(Z,A)\to H^\ast(Y\times_X Z, Y\times_X A)
$$
is an isomorphism, for every pair of spaces $(Z,A)$ and every map $Z\to X$.

We may assume that $(Z,A)$ is a CW pair, and by an inverse limit argument we may assume that it is a finite CW pair, and by a five-lemma argument we may reduce to the case when the pair is $(D^n,S^{n-1})$ for some $n\ge 0$. Another five-lemma argument and induction over $n$ reduces us to the case when $Z$ is a point and $A$ is empty. To put it another way, as functors of $(Z,A)$ both sides are cohomology theories, so the map is an isomorphism for all $Z$ if it is so for a point. (We are using that $H^\ast(Y)$ is flat over $H^\ast(X)$.)

So the task is to show that, under our assumptions, the cohomology of the fiber of $Y\to X$ is the tensor product $H^\ast(Y)\otimes_{H^\ast(X)} R$. I have not thought this through, but it seems that it should follow without much trouble from the Serre spectral sequence of $Y\to X$.